# Copying columns within pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I want to slice and copy columns in a Python Dataframe. My data frame looks like the following:

```
     1928  1928.1  1929  1929.1  1930  1930.1
 0    0     0       0     0       0     0
 1    1     3       3     2       2     2
 2    4     1       3     0       1     2
```

I want to make it of the form

```
     1928  1928.1  1929 1929.1 1930 1930.1
 0   0     0            
 1   1     3          
 2   4     1                    
 3   0     0
 4   3     2
 5   3     0
 6   0     0
 7   2     2
 8   1     2
```

Which basically means that I want to shift the values in Columns '1929','1929.1','1930','1930.1' under the column '1928' and '1928.1'

For the same, I wrote the code as

```
   [In]x=2
       y=2
       b=3
       c=x-1
       for a in range(0,2):
            df.iloc[b:(b+3),0:x]=df.iloc[0:3,x:(x+y)]
            x=x+2
            b=b+3
   [In] df
   [Out] 
     1928  1928.1  1929  1929.1  1930  1930.1
 0    0     0       0     0       0     0
 1    1     3       3     2       2     2
 2    4     1       3     0       1     2
```

No copying takes places within the columns. How shall I modify my code??

Comment: Have you tried any of the methods from [Merge, join, and concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merge-join-and-concatenate)?

Comment: I guess it belongs to the same dataframe, so it might rule out the option of concat, merge or join

Comment: Does the order matter to you?

Comment: yes sir, it does !!

Comment: Do you want to keep the empty columns?

Comment: No sir, I don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

```
cols = ['1929', '1929.1', '1930', '1930.1']
vals = df[cols].values.reshape(-1, 2)
```

**`numpy.vstack`** with **`append`**:

```
df[['1928', '1928.1']].append(
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.vstack([vals[::2], vals[1::2]]), columns = ['1928', '1928.1']
    )
)

   1928  1928.1
0     0       0
1     1       3
2     4       1
0     0       0
1     3       2
2     3       0
3     0       0
4     2       2
5     1       2
```

Answer (score 1):

If your're ok with having a new dataframe, simply concatenate the columns:

```
df1 = df[['1928','1928.1']]
df2 = df[['1929','1929.1']]
df2.columns = ['1928','1928.1']
df3 = df[['1930','1930.1']]
df3.columns = ['1928','1928.1']

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
```

I think thats the most readable, and easiest way. You can overwrite your original dataframe and discard the others.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

cols = df.columns

res = pd.DataFrame({cols[0]: list(chain.from_iterable(df.iloc[:, ::2].T.values)),
                    cols[1]: list(chain.from_iterable(df.iloc[:, 1::2].T.values))})\
        .join(pd.DataFrame(columns=cols[2:]))

print(res)

   1928  1928.1 1929 1929.1 1930 1930.1
0     0       0  NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
1     1       3  NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
2     4       1  NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
3     0       0  NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
4     3       2  NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
5     3       0  NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
6     0       0  NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
7     2       2  NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
8     1       2  NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the the first four characters of the column names

```
#def key(s):
#    return s[:4]
#gb = df.groupby(key, axis=1)
gb = df.groupby(by=df.columns.str[:4], axis=1)

n_cols = len(df.columns) // len(gb)
col_names = df.iloc[:,:n_cols].columns
```

For each group's DataFrame, rename the columns and concatenate  - this produces a new DataFrame with only two columns

```
dz = pd.concat(d.rename(columns=dict(item for item in zip(d.columns,col_names))) for g,d in gb)
dz.index = range(len(dz))
```

---

```
frames = []
for g,d in gb:
    d.columns = col_names
    frames.append(d)
dy = pd.concat(frames)
dy.index = range(len(dy))
```

---

Will work for more than six columns.
Relies on all groups having the same number of columns.
Relies on columns being sorted by their labels.